# Does ReactiveUI offers PRISM ViewModelLocator like service?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, reactiveui

With PRISM framework we do like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectName.MyView"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
</UserControl>
```

As a result, our `DataContext` set with instance of `MyViewModel`.

I tried to find the same technique in ReactiveUI and all I have found is this [link](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/#viewmodels). It says that all you need is implement `IActivatableViewModel` in your viewmodel and if you have `WhenActivated` block in view code-behind that implement `IViewFor<T>` view model get activated.

**Questions:**

1). What does "get activated" mean? I expect that view model is set by ReactiveUI automatically, but this behavior doesn't occur, so looks like that I misunderstood what "get activated" actually means.
2). Does ReactiveUI provide such service which set view model when view become activated? If yes, could you please provide code samples.

Comment: ReactiveUI is view model first based approach. So you will create the view model and navigation will create a view for the view model. https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/main/wpf/ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing

This is the opposite of prism which is view first, you create a view and it creates a view model for that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does "get activated" mean?

Activation is used to defer the setup of a view model until the corresponing view has been loaded: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated.

> I expect that view model is set by ReactiveUI automatically ...

Your expectation is wrong. In ReactiveUI, the view is resolved based on the view model (as opposed to the view model being resolved by the view using a view model locator in Prism).

> Does ReactiveUI provide such service which set view model when view become activated?

No. You should create the view model yourself and let ReactiveUI resolve the corresponding view. Check out the [Routing section](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/) in the docs for an example.